# Wordpress query for Custom Field number BETWEEN two query variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to list an archive of queried custom post types named 'jobs', each with a custom field of 'minimum_salary' and 'maximum_salary'.

On the previous search page the user enters two values in the search ('min-salary' & 'max-salary'), which are added to the URL of the archive page.

I want to be able to display ALL jobs that have a 'minimum_salary' AND 'maximum_salary' BETWEEN the min and max salary var the user entered on the previous page.

See below for my code so far, thanks for the help.

```
<?php

$minSalaryVar = get_query_var('min-salary');
$maxSalaryVar = get_query_var('max-salary');

$taxArgs = array();


if ($minSalaryVar && $maxSalaryVar) {
  $taxArgs[] = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'minimum_salary',
        'value' => array($minSalaryVar, $maxSalaryVar),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'numeric'
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'maximum_salary',
        'value' => array($minSalaryVar, $maxSalaryVar),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'numeric'
      ),
    )
  );
}




   if ($taxArgs) {
  $args = array (
  'tax_query' => $taxArgs,
  );

  $argsNew = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, $args );
  query_posts( $argsNew );
} ?>
```

Comment: Try changing to `array(
    'key' => 'minimum_salary',
    'value' => $minSalaryVar,
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'numeric'
),
  array(
      'key' => 'maximum_salary',
      'value' => $maxSalaryVar,
      'compare' => '<=',
      'type' => 'numeric'
  ),`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this doesn't seem to work either. It just lists every post, regardless of what minimum and maximum salary is specified

Comment: what are you using as input for minimum and maximum salary?

Comment: I'm using a JQuery Slider to input the minimum and maximum salary, which gets added to the URL like so:

/?s=&min-salary=28000&max-salary=70000

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'compare' = 'BETWEEN' two times when you need either using it just once or compare twice one greater than minimum salary and the other bigger. Following I'll let both options:

1:

```
if ($minSalaryVar && $maxSalaryVar) {
    $meta_query = array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key' => 'minimum_salary',
        'value' => $minSalaryVar, 
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'numeric'
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'maximum_salary',
        'value' => $maxSalaryVar,
        'compare' => '<=',
        'type' => 'numeric'
      ),
  );
}




   if ($taxArgs) {
  $args = array (
  'meta_query' => $meta_query,
  );

  $argsNew = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, $args );
  query_posts( $argsNew );
} ?>
```

2:

```
$taxArgs = array();


if ($minSalaryVar && $maxSalaryVar) {
  $meta_query = array(
        'key' => 'minimum_salary',
        'value' => array($minSalaryVar,$maxSalaryVar),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN
        'type' => 'numeric'
  );
}




   if ($taxArgs) {
  $args = array (
  'meta_query' => $meta_query,
  );

  $argsNew = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, $args );
  query_posts( $argsNew );
} ?>
```

--- EDIT

You should use 'meta_query' instead of 'tax_query'

Comment: None of these suggestions work unfortunately, but you can have multiple things to test against since like version 4.1

Comment: It might be because you are using 'tax_query' when you want to use 'meta_query' within $args

Comment: BTW, it isn't a versions things. Its just that you aren't specifying correct&logical bounds for your desired sql sentence.